# Buscador Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Buenos días, tengo este tipo de tabla,

```
 <table id="table" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Titulo del documento</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Proyecto</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Estado</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Idioma</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Nº del documento</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Versión</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Revisión</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Descripción</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Fecha</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Subcategoria</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Confidencialidad</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Tipo de documento</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Usuario</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Aprobado por</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Autorizado por</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Revisor</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Compañia</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Codigo proyecto</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Edición</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Eliminar</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                                        <tr>
                        <td>Prueba 1</td>
                        <td>ACR</td>
                        <td>Aprobado</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Prueba</td>
                        <td>2017-05-09</td>
                        <td>COR</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>RPT</td>
                        <td>ACD</td>
                        <td>ACD</td>
                        <td>ACD</td>
                        <td>ACD</td>
                        <td>DAU</td>
                        <td>Prueba 1-RPT-DAU-COR-ACR-2017-</td>
 </table>
```

En la que muestra resultados obtenidos de un Select * de una BBDD.
Quiero añadirle un buscador con Jquery para que quede totalmente dinamico, pero a la hora de añadirselo estaba buscando por el foro y "supuestamente" seria como un codigo generico, y la verdad que de Jquery no entiendo casi nada.
Seria este.

```
<script>
$("#search").keyup(function () {
            _this = this;
            // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
            $.each($("#table tbody tr"), function () {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
                    $(this).hide();
                else
                    $(this).show();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Pero a la hora de probar el buscador no funciona

El buscador lo tengo fuera de la tabla, digo esto por qeu no se si es correcto.

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search..." />
```

P.D. la libreria Jquery esta bien insertada ya que tengo otra opción diseñada en Jquery que genera un codigo automaticamente en otor input pero los "ID" no son los mismos.

Aun asi, este codigo no creo que le este generando conflictos no?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#titulo_documento, #compania1, #acro_subcategoria, #acro_proyecto, #fecha, #idioma, #acro_documento, #proyecto, #estado, #num_documento, \n\
    #version, #revision, #descripcion, #confidencialidad, #acro_usuario1, #aprobado_por1, #autorizado_por1, #revisor1').blur(function () {
                $('#codigo_proyecto').val($('#titulo_documento').val() + "-" + $('#acro_documento').val() + "-" + $('#compania1').val() + "-" + $('#acro_subcategoria').val() + "-" + $('#acro_proyecto').val() + "-" + $('#fecha').val() + "-(" + $('#idioma').val() + ")");
            });
        });
        function change_documento()
        {
            var acro_documento = $("#acro_documento").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "subcategoria.php",
                data: "acro_documento=" + acro_documento,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response)
                {
                    //alert(response);return false;
                    $("#acro_subcategoria").html(response);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Para preguntas de javascript es recomendable no poner el codigo del servidor si no el procesado en navegador. Todo ese `php` no nos dice nada en esta situacion. Puedes pegar el resultado? Un saludo

Comment: Vale, no tenia ni idea de eso, cogi el codigo que me genera en "F12" no se si es esto justo lo que os puede servir como guia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas en esta línea del jQuery:

```
$.each($("#table tbody tr"), function () {
//               ^^^^^
```

Estás utilizando un selector que no existe en tu estructura html. Tienes el elemento `table` con id `#table` , dentro un elemento `thead` y seguido tu elemento `tr`.

Posible solución: quita el selector `tbody` en la linea de `jQuery` o añade el elemento `tbody` en tu estructura `HTML` de tal manera que el segundo `tr` quede dentro de este.

Comment: Te digo lo mismo que Asier de nignuna de las dos formas me funciona, algo estoy haciendo mal pero no se le que

Comment: @AlbertoCeperodeAndrés Ojo porque no estás cerrando el segundo elemento tr de tu tabla, no veo por ninguna parte la etiqueta de cierre. Corrígelo y me cuentas.

Comment: Si no me equivoco ahora que procesee el codigo por JSFiddle si esta cerrado creo. https://jsfiddle.net/synysevend90/0j8x3f6r/1/ Ademas en NetBeans me los marca en amarillo

Comment: En ese fiddle tu tabla tiene un tbody por cada tr cuando solo debería haber uno para toda la tabla. Antes de seguir probando con ensayo error deberías revisar bien la estructura html que generas.

Comment: diste con la solución el HTML estaba mal creado, muchisimas gracias crack, lo fui revisando uno a uno cada tr y td hasta que di con la tecla!

Answer (score 2):

El código funciona, al menos en algunos navegadores.

Para asegurarte de que funcione en cualquier navegador agrega el tag tbody que utilizas en el selector.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo funcionando:

```js
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  _this = this;
  // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
  $.each($("#table tbody tr"), function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
      $(this).hide();
    else
      $(this).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search..." />
<table id="table" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Titulo del documento</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Proyecto</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Estado</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Idioma</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Nº del documento</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Versión</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Revisión</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Descripción</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Fecha</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Subcategoria</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Confidencialidad</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Tipo de documento</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Usuario</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Aprobado por</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Autorizado por</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Revisor</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Compañia</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Codigo proyecto</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Edición</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;">Eliminar</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Título Buscar</td>
      <td>Proyecto Buscar</td>
      <td>Estado Buscar</td>
      <td>Idioma Buscar</td>
      <td>Num Doc Buscar</td>
      <td>Versión Buscar</td>
      <td>Revisión Buscar</td>
      <td>Descripción Buscar</td>
      <td>Fecha Buscar</td>
      <td>Subcategoría Buscar</td>
      <td>Confidencialidad Buscar</td>
      <td>Tipo Doc Buscar</td>
      <td>Acro Usuario Buscar</td>
      <td>Aprobado Buscar</td>
      <td>Autorizado Buscar</td>
      <td>Revisor Buscar</td>
      <td>Compañía Buscar</td>
      <td>Cod Proyecto Buscar</td>
      <td>
        <a href="?action=editar&id=1&id1=1&id2=1&id3=1"><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="?action=eliminar&titulo_documento=1&num_documento=1&version=1&revision=1"><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Título Otro texto</td>
      <td>Proyecto Otro texto</td>
      <td>Estado Otro texto</td>
      <td>Idioma Otro texto</td>
      <td>Num Doc Otro texto</td>
      <td>Versión Otro texto</td>
      <td>Revisión Otro texto</td>
      <td>Descripción Otro texto</td>
      <td>Fecha Otro texto</td>
      <td>Subcategoría Otro texto</td>
      <td>Confidencialidad Otro texto</td>
      <td>Tipo Doc Otro texto</td>
      <td>Acro Usuario Otro texto</td>
      <td>Aprobado Otro texto</td>
      <td>Autorizado Otro texto</td>
      <td>Revisor Otro texto</td>
      <td>Compañía Otro texto</td>
      <td>Cod Proyecto Otro texto</td>
      <td>
        <a href="?action=editar&id=2&id1=2&id2=2&id3=2"><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="?action=eliminar&titulo_documento=2&num_documento=2&version=2&revision=2"><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Título Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Proyecto Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Estado Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Idioma Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Num Doc Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Versión Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Revisión Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Descripción Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Fecha Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Subcategoría Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Confidencialidad Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Tipo Doc Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Acro Usuario Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Aprobado Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Autorizado Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Revisor Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Compañía Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>Cod Proyecto Texto busqueda</td>
      <td>
        <a href="?action=editar&id=13&id1=13&id2=13&id3=13"><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="?action=eliminar&titulo_documento=13&num_documento=13&version=13&revision=13"><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Que raro, no soy capaz de hacerlo funcionar, algo estare haciendo mal

Comment: Ya ves que funciona. Sin más información va a ser difícil ayudarte

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/synysevend90/0j8x3f6r/ No funcionara porque contiene codigo del servidor pero si comparo mi codigo con el tuyo yo lo veo exactamente igual diria yo :S
La uncia diferencia es que en uno recibe los resultados del servidor y en otros los metemos a pelo pero eso no deberia de ser problema,que pienso yo xD! Añadi un poco más de codigo por si le estubeira generando conflicto al final del post inicial

Comment: En jsfiddle no puedes meter código PHP, te puede corromper el DOM con etiquetas inesperadas y no te genera valores ni comportamientos reales. O nos proporcionas una versión en vivo de tu página o el código HTML generado por el PHP (pulsando control+u en chrome, por ejemplo).

Comment: Perfecto, no seria como ver el codigo fuente de la pagina lo de control+u?

https://jsfiddle.net/synysevend90/0j8x3f6r/1/

Comment: En el jsfiddle te falta añadir la librería jQuery. Pulsa sobre la configuración de JAVASCRIPT y selecciona "jQuery 3.2.1" en "FRAMEWORK & EXTENSIONS". Luego pulsa el botón "Ejecutar" y prueba otra vez

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer algo del estilo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Filterable Table</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>  
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
<p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>

</body>
</html>
```